# UserControl: Can I set my own DependencyProperty in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl() => InitializeComponent();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

    public DataTemplate MyTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate) GetValue(MyTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTemplateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"> <!-- etc. -->
    <Grid />

    <!-- does not compile-->
    <UserControl.MyTemplate>
        <DataTemplate />
    </UserControl.MyTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

But it doesn't work. Not-so-surprisingly, when you start an element name with `UserControl`, the compiler only looks for properties defined on `UserControl` itself. But changing the element name to `<MyControl.MyTemplate>` (with the proper namespace prefix) doesn't work either; the compiler tries to interpret `MyTemplate` as an attached property in this case.

Is there any way to achieve this aside from defining the value in a resource and then assigning it to the property from codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the property by a Style:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:MyControl.MyTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Good idea! But why without TargetType? It seems to work fine with one...

Comment: @dlf You mean with `TargetType="local:MyControl"`? My XAML designer doesn't like that. Although it works at runtime...

Comment: I did `TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}"`, and VS2017 and R# were both ok with it.